# EPPlus vertical alignment of text to center of merged cells is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus

I am trying to vertical align the text to the center but its not working. Text is coming at the bottom of merged cell. Here is the minimal code that is not working.

```
// get handle to the existing worksheet
ExcelWorksheet worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("mysheet");

//[row,col]
worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "a1";
worksheet.Cells[2, 1].Value = "a1";
worksheet.Cells[3, 1].Value = "a1";
worksheet.Cells[4, 1].Value = "a1";
worksheet.Cells[5, 1].Value = "a1";
worksheet.Cells[6, 1].Value = "a1";

//comment out below six lines to make it work
worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "11";
worksheet.Cells[2, 2].Value = "12";
worksheet.Cells[3, 2].Value = "13";
worksheet.Cells[4, 2].Value = "14";
worksheet.Cells[5, 2].Value = "15";
worksheet.Cells[6, 2].Value = "16";
//comment out above six lines to make it work

worksheet.Cells["A1:A6"].Merge = true;
worksheet.Cells["A1:A6"].Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Center;

xlPackage.Save();
```

Please help.

Adding these lines at the end makes it work:

worksheet.Column(1).Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Center;
worksheet.Column(2).Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Center;

That means I have to center align all the columns in order to center align the first column.

Comment: That should work.  Maybe post more of your code, it could be something else overriding it.

Comment: What version of EPPlus are you using?  Is the code you posted the only thing you are doing to the package?  It works fine for me when I try it.

Comment: Its EPPlus 4.0.5.0. Yes, the posted code is the only thing I am doing, I have simplified my code to bare minimum to focus on the problem itself. Its not working on my side.

Answer (score 7):

Try this...

```
using OfficeOpenXml.Style;
worksheet.Cells["A1:A6"].Style.VerticalAlignment = 
ExcelVerticalAlignment.Center;
```

or ...
worksheet.Cells["A1:A6"]. =
OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelVerticalAlignment.Center;

Comment: For the Powershell folks who landed here: `$worksheet.Cells[$worksheet.Dimension.Address].Style.VerticalAlignment = [OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelVerticalAlignment]::Top
$worksheet.Cells[$worksheet.Dimension.Address].Style.HorizontalAlignment = [OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment]::Left`

Answer (score -3):

Try this...

```
worksheet.Range["A1", "A6"].VerticalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: It requires Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel which needs MS Office. I don't have it installed.